# Perform Auto-Type into Another Window

Tags: vb.net, automation

Good Morning,

Programming in VB.NET.
I'm trying to see if there's a way I can perform either an automatic paste or auto-type (if you've used KeePass before, similar to the auto-type function in that) into a form of another window.

The application doesn't have to figure out which form to type it in, similar to KeePass you select the option then it will switch tabs to the next tab (like ALT+TAB to whatever the previous window was) and then auto type or paste wherever the cursor currently is.

Here's a step by step of what I'm trying to accomplish:
1. System launches with Windows start up and loads into System tray
2. User is inputting notes into their system.
3. User right clicks system tray icon and clicks "Insert Signature"
4. Application then pastes or auto-types whatever is in that variable into the window they were in @ the current focus of the cursor.

I would prefer an auto-type kind of function for applications that don't accept paste but if it has that limitation that is OK. I'm fairly certain I could figure out how to make it auto-type if I could at least figure out how to get it to input into another windows form.

Does any of what I am trying to do make sense?

Comment: This should help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It makes total sense i think using clipboard feature will unable you to do so.

Here's a link for reference:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

- ContainsText()/ContainsText(TextDataFormat) and GetText()/GetText(TextDataFormat) would be needed to check if it contains text(unicode) and copy to clipboard respectively.
- and for autotyping you may watch this video on YOUTUBE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWwrbalASlQ

Hope this Helps!!!